# Error al mover proyecto de un ordenador a otro

Tags: xcode

Me da este error al cambiar el proyecto a otro Mac:

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use v to see invocation) objective-c

He intentado pod `install`, `clean`, etc no sé qué más hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Tenía una referencia a un archivo que en el nuevo Mac no existía, la borré y funcionó, el fichero era libpods.a lo descubrí porque intenté todo, pod install en el terminal del mac, sudo gem install cocoapods en el terminal del mac, incluso enable_bitcode = no (que está en el buid setting del proyecto), volví a agregar todos los framework que utiliza mi proyecto, como nada de lo que encontraba funcionó en la parte del explorador del proyecto fui a la carpeta frameworks y vi que libpods.a estaba en rojo y en la carpeta del finder ese archivo no estaba lo borré (importante yo tenía copia del proyecto).

Comment: ¿Cómo encontraste que ese era el error?

Comment: Al cambiar el proyecto de mac me quedó libPods.a en el nuevo Mac, lo borré y me funcionó

Comment: La cosa es que esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por su longitud y contenido, pero creo que podría ser de utilidad para otros usuarios si pudieras [editarla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/131624/edit) para añadir algo más de detalle (en particular, ¿cómo encontraste qué fichero era el que fallaba?¿lo encontraste en el log o en un mensaje de error?)